# PHP realpath returns blank on localhost

Tags: php, iis, localhost, realpath

I'm new to PHP but have a very frustrating, seemingly simple problem

```
echo realpath("../../Database/mydb.mdb");
```

Works perfectly on a live server **but** returns blank on localhost!

I may be barking up the wrong tree , but is it a PHP setting in IIS I'm missing ?

> localhost running PHP 5.6.31 and IIS 10

Comment: do you really have the path in your localhost ? is your `Database` directory inside another 2 directories in the web root ?

Comment: I'm looking for the PHP equivalent of Server.MapPath in ASP with the purpose of creating a connection string.

Comment: The test page is in a separate folder, the site structure is the same on ht e live server as the localhost, so it should return the same answer.

Comment: this is the live server response C:\Inetpub\vhosts\myweb.co.uk\httpdocs\database\myDB.mdb

Comment: What is the localhost directory structure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)- `realpath()` returns FALSE on failure, e.g. if the file does not exist.

So it seems in your localhost, you may not have the file structure as you said.

From the same source : The running script must have executable permissions on all directories in the hierarchy, otherwise `realpath()` will return FALSE.

So, also make sure that there is no  permission issue.

**EDIT:**
From [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php):
The function realpath() will not work for a file which is inside a Phar as such path would be a virual path, not a real one.

That is `realpath(..)` won't work for any virtual directory, it will work only if the path is real i.e. not virtual.

Comment: The file definitely exists, and I've checked permission too. The site folder has full permissions, do the permissions need to be from the system root or the site root?

Comment: Tell us the full directory structure of the file in your localhost, that is it.

Comment: C:\Users\Andrew\Sites\MWsite\Database\myDB.mdb

Comment: @user1601686, what is the location of your web root folder, i,e, htodocs if you are using Xampp ?

Comment: page I'm testing from C:\Users\Andrew\Sites\MWsite\Testing\PHP\test.php

Comment: @user1601686, what is your webroot - Sites? What software are you using to create the server- Xampp, Wampp ?

Comment: running from a virtual directory under iis 10, could this be the issue ?

Comment: is 'Sites' the web root directory ?

Comment: MWSite is the site root

Comment: This is the problem, now I need to find a solution: - FROM PHP SITE Well, there's the problem: realpath() is an OS filesystem function and doesn't give a damn about any "virtual" stuff IIS might provide. No bug.